# Setting the correct zoom level from Sector bounds for flat map using WorldWind SDK

Tags: markers, extents, zoom, altitude, worldwind

This is not coming out correct for me. Setting the zoom level based on some other code I got on here using the EarthFlat model, which does not set the correct zoom for the placemarks within a sector bounds.

```
private void invoke() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            ArrayList<Position> pos = new ArrayList<Position>();
            pos.add(Position.fromDegrees(32, -117));
            pos.add(Position.fromDegrees(48, -72));
            pos.add(Position.fromDegrees(40, -70));

            final Sector bounds = Sector.boundingSector(pos);

            setWwPanel(new WWPanel());
            final WWPanel wwPanel = getWwPanel();
            wwPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) getSize().getWidth(), (int) getSize().getHeight()));
            wwPanel.getWwd().addGLEventListener(new GLEventListener() {

                public void display(GLAutoDrawable e) {
                    //System.out.println("Map displayed");
                }

                public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable e) {
                    System.out.println("Map disposed");
                }

                public void init(GLAutoDrawable e) {
                    System.out.println("Map GL initialized");
                }

                public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable e, int arg1,
                        int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
                    System.out.println("Map reshaped");
                }

            });

            LayerList layerList = new LayerList();
            BMNGWMSLayer bmng = new BMNGWMSLayer();
            layerList.add(bmng);
            ViewControlsLayer vcl = new ViewControlsLayer();
            vcl.setShowPitchControls(false);
            vcl.setShowVeControls(false);
            vcl.setShowHeadingControls(false);
            layerList.add(vcl);
            Model flatModel = new BasicModel(new EarthFlat(), layerList);
            ((EarthFlat) flatModel.getGlobe()).setProjection(FlatGlobe.PROJECTION_MERCATOR);
            wwPanel.getWwd().setModel(flatModel);
            wwPanel.getWwd().addSelectListener(new ViewControlsSelectListener(wwPanel.getWwd(), vcl));

            RenderableLayer rl = new RenderableLayer();
            for(Position curPos : pos) {
                PointPlacemark pm = new PointPlacemark(curPos);
                pm.setAltitudeMode(WorldWind.RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
                pm.setLabelText("Test");
                PointPlacemarkAttributes pma = new PointPlacemarkAttributes();

                pma.setImageColor(Color.GREEN);
                pma.setLabelFont(Font.decode("Verdana-Bold-11"));
                pma.setLabelMaterial(Material.GREEN);
                pm.setAttributes(pma);
                pm.setValue(AVKey.DISPLAY_NAME, "Text displayed on mouse over");

                rl.addRenderable(pm);
            }

            layerList.add(rl);

            BasicOrbitView fov = (BasicOrbitView) wwPanel.getWwd().getView();
            fov.setCenterPosition(Position.fromDegrees(bounds.getCentroid().getLatitude().degrees, bounds.getCentroid().getLongitude().degrees));

// this is what i am using to set zoom ??????
            double radius = wwPanel.getWwd().getModel().getExtent().getRadius();
            double viewRange = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(bounds.getMaxLatitude().degrees-bounds.getMinLatitude().degrees, 2)+Math.pow(bounds.getMaxLongitude().degrees-bounds.getMinLongitude().degrees, 2));
            double altitude = radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(viewRange * 0.5));

            fov.setZoom(altitude);

            add(getWwPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

    });
}
```

It sets the zoom fine, but the placemarks are off the view bounds.

Expected result:

[image]

Undesired/actual result:

[image]